# Conversion of Mat image in C++ to C# bitmap and vice-versa

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, image-processing

We have an Console application that sends the image to the C++ dll and the C++ dll converts the image to Mat format and does the image preprocessing and sends the image back to the console application.

We are facing issue in converting the preprocessed image back to bitmap so that i can use it in C# console application for further process.

C++ Dll code:

```
nsigned char* PreProcessImage(unsigned char* img, long data_len, int* bytes_count, unsigned char* data, int width, int height, int iScaleFactor, int iErodeValue, int iDilateValue, int iSmoothValue, int iThreshType, int iThreshMinValue, int iThreshMaxValue, bool IsWhiteOnBlack)
{
    /*try
    {*/
        vector<unsigned char> inputImageBytes(img, img + data_len);

        cv::Mat mat = imdecode(inputImageBytes, IMREAD_COLOR);

        int iRetValue = 0;

        /*cv::Mat mat(height, width, CV_8UC(channels));

        memcpy(mat.data, (img), static_cast<size_t>(width * height));*/

        cv::Mat lImage = mat.clone();

        //cv::InputArray arrImg = lImage;

        cv::imwrite("AbCdE.bmp", lImage);

        cv::Mat grayImage;

        cv::cvtColor(lImage, grayImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        int iImageWidth = grayImage.cols;

        int iImageHeight = grayImage.rows;

        double multipleFactor = 1; 
        
        MultipleFactorValue(iScaleFactor);

        cv::Size outputSize(static_cast<int>(iImageWidth * multipleFactor), static_cast<int>(iImageHeight * multipleFactor));

        cv::Mat outputImage(outputSize, CV_8UC3);

        cv::resize(grayImage, outputImage, outputSize);

        cv::Mat lOutImage;

        // Smooth
        if (iSmoothValue > 0) {
            cv::GaussianBlur(outputImage, outputImage, cv::Size(iSmoothValue, iSmoothValue), 0, 0);
        }

        // Threshold
        if (iThreshType == 0) {
            cv::threshold(outputImage, lOutImage, iThreshMinValue, iThreshMaxValue, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
        }
        else {
            cv::adaptiveThreshold(outputImage, lOutImage, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY, 3, 0);
        }

        // Erode
        cv::Mat se = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS, cv::Size(3, 3));

        cv::Scalar borderValue = cv::Scalar(255);

        if (iErodeValue > 0) {
            cv::erode(lOutImage, lOutImage, se, cv::Point(-1, -1), iErodeValue, 0, borderValue);
        }

        // Dilate
        if (iDilateValue > 0) {
            cv::dilate(lOutImage, lOutImage, se, cv::Point(-1, -1), iDilateValue, 0, borderValue);
        }

        if (IsWhiteOnBlack) {
            cv::bitwise_not(lOutImage, lOutImage);
        }

        int size = lImage.total() * lImage.elemSize();
        unsigned char* raw_bytes = new unsigned char[size];

        memcpy(raw_bytes, lImage.data, size * sizeof(uchar));

        *bytes_count = size;
        return raw_bytes;

        /*cv::copyTo(lImage, outImage, );

        return iRetValue;*/
    //}
    /*catch(Exception)
    {
        return ;
    }*/
    
}
```

C# console code:

```
public static unsafe void CallingClass()
        {
            //Load image from file
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imagePath);
            byte[] imageData = LoadImage();

            width = bitmap.Width;
            height = bitmap.Height;
            channel = 2;

           // outImg = new Mat(width, height, MatType.CV_8UC1);

            IntPtr ptr = PreProcessImage(imageData, length, out int bytes_count, out byte[] data, width, height, 1, 0, 0, 0, 70, 70, 90, false);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bytes_count];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, bytes_count);

            Bitmap img = IntPtrToBitmap(ptr, width,height, bytes_count);

           // Image<Bgr, byte> image = ByteArrayToImage(bytes);

            //outImg.Save("Output.bmp");

            //Cv2.ImWrite("Output.bmp", outImg);

            //Console.WriteLine(textPtr);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

static Bitmap IntPtrToBitmap(IntPtr ptr, int width, int height, int size)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);

            try
            {
                // Copy the image data from the IntPtr to the Bitmap
                Marshal.Copy(ptr, new byte[size * 4], 0, size * 4);
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    IntPtr sourceRow = ptr + (y * width * 4);
                    IntPtr destinationRow = bitmapData.Scan0 + (y * bitmapData.Stride);
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        Marshal.Copy(sourceRow, new byte[4], 0, 4);
                        Marshal.Copy(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 255 }, 0, sourceRow, 4); // Set alpha to 255
                        Marshal.Copy(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 255 }, 0, destinationRow, 4);
                        sourceRow += 4;
                        destinationRow += 4;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }

            return bitmap;
        }
```

i have tried converting it into byte array and sending it via marshal class but the image is not as inputted it shifts and repeats the characters written in it.

Comment: To create a bitmap from raw data you need: 1) the actual data 2) the pixel format 3) the stride, 4) width/height. If stride and pixel format are missing you are making some assumptions about what these are, and if there is shifting in the image, chances are good that these assumptions are wrong.

Comment: I.e. either use an OpenCV wrapper that provides a "ToBitmap"-method, Or post what `IntPtrToBitmap`, since it likely contains errors. Also note that you are leaking memory, you should probably give `PreProcessImage` a pointer to write the result to, instead of returning a pointer that needs cleanup.

Comment: @JonasH I have already tried with the above parameters but it doesn't work. The image that I receive was corrupted. Also we know that there is a memory leak in the returning the pointer, Originally we were passing the image as an reference but still the main issue was it was not working.

Comment: Tried *what*? You obviously has a bug. The bug is likely in the conversion code. It is fairly easy to make mistakes with the indices etc, but there are not many ways to write such code correctly, so mistakes can be fairly easy to spot. But we cannot tell you if there are errors in code you have not shown.

Comment: I have edited the post please check that and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking the pixel format of the input bitmap. I.e.

```
if(bitmap.PixelFormat != Format32bppArgb){
    throw new InvalidOperation($"Invalid input format, expected 32bit bgr, got {bitmap.PixelFormat}");
}
```

The code is kind of painful to read, since there is so much stuff that is apparently unused, and still parts missing. But your code is only valid for 32 bit BGR images. If your image uses any other pixel format it will just in strange ways. My guess is that the image is *really* a 24 bit BGR, since that is what jpeg uses. Code to copy a 24bit pixel to a 32 bit pixel should look something like:

```
var sourceIndex = (sourceRow + x * 3);
var s = *((uint*)sourceIndex);
s = s  | 0xff000000;
targetRow[x] = s;
```

Do note that the stride is more important for 24-bit images, since it typically needs to be even dividable by 4. You could also just ensure the created bitmap uses the same pixel format as the source.

However, my recommendation would be to use a c# wrapper for openCV, like [emguCV](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images). That would make conversion, and many other things much easier:

```
var image = mat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>()
var bitmap = image.ToBitmap();
```

It may also allow you to stick to c# code, avoiding the need for a c++ project. EmguCv is not free for commercial use, but it is also not very expensive.